# Windows pointer bitmap not being correctly updated

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, winapi, mdi

So, I'm writing a text editor, using MDI.

I have a frame window, child windows and each child window has a text-area window.

Now, my problem is the pointer.  It's not setting itself to the correct bitmap.  So for example, if I move the pointer to the border, it correctly turns into the left-right drag icon.  That's all good and well - but when I then move it into the text-window area, *it doesn't change back to a normal pointer*.  Which is wroooooooong.

Any ideas why the pointer bitmap isn't being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was incorrectly calling LoadCursor().

If you're using a predefined cursor, the first argument, the instance, must be NULL.

My argument was not NULL (and I wasn't checking the return value, *cough!*).

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you're intercepting the event that MDI uses to swap the pointer bitmap back out, without passing it up the chain.

Comment: Good call.  Just in the process of checking out that I'm calling the appropriate default handlers in the appropriate places.  Thing is, everything else works, and you'd expect more to be going wrong if you'd got that wrong.